# Can I create a lock or semaphore in python, without having to pass it directly as an argument?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, locking, celery

We have an application which uses several daemons, including Django, Flask and Celery.

We are using Django rest framework in order to get requests from the client side, and then executing them asynchronously using celery. This means that I might have several concurrent python processes running, but I am not using multiprocessing or other native python concurrent handling.

Nevertheless, I would like to have a shared lock across the different processes. Is there any way to use python's Lock or Semaphore in this kind of use case?

Alternatively, can I use Celery to handle it?

**Edit:**

For my use case it is sufficient to use file locking, as suggested by @Matias Cicero.

However, I selected @Aaron answer as accepted, since he offered using managers, which solves my problem with locks, as well as offering multiple additional shared resources. This is in fact a very useful solution for my needs.

Thank you all!

Comment: Seems to me you want to have a shared lock between processes. How about using a *[file lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking)*?

Comment: you can point a [`multiprocessing.Manager`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager) to a ip/port with `mp.BaseManager.get_server()`. this mamager could be hosted in one of your existing processes, or you could serve it from another process (whichever one starts up first / is guaranteed to be running before the others)

Comment: My processes will be running on the same machine, so I think ip and port might not be the best practice for me. 

file locking sounds like a good idea for my purposes. Is python's filelock package a good idea to use?

Comment: @orizis ip address is unneccessary if it's the local machine, it will use the loopback address by default if none is provided. ports are a pretty common way for processes to communicate, as it prevents the need for looking up the process id and getting a stdin/stdout to read/write from. There's nothing wrong with file locks, but managers are more extensible (helpful for sharing state, locks, queues, etc..)

Comment: That's sounds great. I will look into both of the solutions. Thank you both for a quick and solid answers

Comment: @Aaron  I'm looking into SyncManager, which has 'Lock' that should serve across hosts as you said. However, it seems that I need to hold the lock somewhere and pass it to any process that require it. Isn't there an option to save the lock as part of the manager, then connect to the manager, get the lock, and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described in your last comment is basically exactly what you would do. You would create the lock before you start the sync manager server and register a function to the server object that will return that lock. Then when you connect to the server from other processes you call that registered function to return the lock object (it's actually a proxy object for the lock, but it should function the same. This only has further implications for mutable containers (dicts, lists, etc.) where modifications to a value within the proxy might not update the proxy itself.)

Here is a short example of creating a server that holds a lock and passes proxy objects to clients that request it.

**server.py:** (start this first in it's own terminal window)

```
"""Multiprocessing sync manager server process"""
from multiprocessing import Lock
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class proxy_object_manager(BaseManager): pass
plock = Lock()
proxy_object_manager.register("get_lock", callable=lambda:plock)

#make sure this port is firewalled off from the rest of the world.
#  arbitrary code execution is a very real possibility if this is insecure. 
#  be sure to read up on how this all works if you intend to expose this computer to the internet
m = proxy_object_manager(('',50000), b'password')
m.get_server().serve_forever()
```

**client.py** (open two or more of these in separate terminals, then press enter in one then the other)

```
""" multiprocessing sync client example """
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

# I played around a bit with making more functional subclasses
class proxy_object_client(BaseManager):
    def __init__(self, proxy_getter, *args, **kwargs):
        type(self).register(proxy_getter)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

client = proxy_object_client("get_lock", ("127.0.0.1", 50000), b"password")
client.connect()
plock = client.get_lock()
print(plock)

#test lock functionality
print("aquiring lock")
plock.acquire()
print("got lock")
input("press enter to release lock")
plock.release()
print("lock released")
```

You should see the first instance of client.py acquire the lock right away, however the second instance shouldn't acquire the lock until you release it in the first instance.

## Gotchas:

- In our `client.py`, plock only exposes the public methods of the object it proxies, so private methods (like `__enter__` and `__exit__` which handle the "with" context) must be explicitly exposed or be made available by specifying the proxy type with a subclassed `BaseProxy`.
- It is possible to use the "with" context to start the server as of python 3.3, however you cannot register lambda functions as callables if you use `manager.start()` which is called with `manager.__enter__()` when you use "with" (This is because they can't be pickled (perhaps just on windows) and sent to the subprocess it creates)
- It is also imperative to use the `if __name__ == "__main__":` idiom in server.py to start the server if you're going to use `manager.start()` or the "with" context as these start a subprocess that will reload the main module, causing effectively a fork bomb. Fortunately the multiprocessing module is smart enough to recognize this and won't do it, but in that case it just throws an exception. (in general if using `multiprocessing`, never create any subprocesses outside of the `if __name__ ...` condition.)

Here's an example of "server.py" that addresses (somewhat) these concerns:

```
from multiprocessing import Lock, freeze_support
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager


class proxy_object_manager(BaseManager): pass
plock = Lock()
def lock_getter():
    return plock
proxy_object_manager.register("get_lock", callable=lock_getter, exposed=['acquire', 'release', '__enter__', '__exit__'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    freeze_support() #needed on windows
    with proxy_object_manager(('127.0.0.1',50000), b'password'):
        input("press enter to stop server")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
It was really helpful and I appreciate the effort you put into giving this example.
If I understand correctly, I must register each shared resource as many times as I want to use it. It makes some duplications in the code. Can I register it once with the callable, and then register another time, as part of the manager class, for reusing? 

In short- can I reuse managers to avoid multiple configurations?

Comment: @orizis one manager can have many things registered to it, but I'll admit it's still not a very fluid interface. I'm looking more into how this could be made pretty, but I think behind the scenes it would be ugly no matter what.

Comment: @orizis the more I look into it, the more I see that managers were really mostly made for sharing with child processes. The server option seems like something they realized could be added on cheaply, but the framework was not designed with it in mind.

Comment: A small price to pay in order to synchronize resources for all python processes. Thanks a lot for introducing it!